# Find a string memory using lldb

Tags: string, macos, lldb, mach-o

Hello I'm trying to find the address of a string in lldb on mac os.

In GDB I would use the `find` command with the addresses to search between.
But I cannot find such a command for lldb, I know that the string is in the cstring section which in my case is `0x00000000002e4f08-0x000000000032e0a8`. 
But i need to know exactly where.

Comment: Does it have a symbol you could use?

Comment: @trojanfoe I dont know exactly what you mean with symbol, but when i type 'cstring <program>' outside of lldb the string is there so I guess yes?

Comment: Well if the program has debug info then the answer will be yes, so that will be the best route.  Investigate how to query symbol info (possibly `image lookup ...`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have access to the Xcode 6 pre-release tools, the lldb includes a new `memory find` command that does this.  Enrico added a quick implementation of this command a few months ago.

Comment: Alright thanks, I dont have access to the tools but I guess there currently is no way, but I found a way around it anyway.

Answer (score 6):

A simple example that uses three lldb commands `image dump sections`, `memory find`, `memory read` to find a string inside a stripped, release app.

```
(lldb) image dump sections MyAppBinary 
[0x0000010462c000-0x00000107744000] 0x0003118000 MyApp`__TEXT
[0x00000107744000-0x00000107d48000] 0x0000604000 MyApp`__DATA
/* removed sections for brevity */

(lldb) mem find -s "youtube" -- 0x00000107744000 0x00000107d48000
data found at location: 0x10793362c
0x10793362c: 79 6f 75 74 75 62 65 2e 63 6f 6d 2f 65 6d 62 65  youtube.com/embe


(lldb) memory read -c100 0x10793362c
0x10793362c: 79 6f 75 74 75 62 65 2e 63 6f 6d 2f 65 6d 62 65  youtube.com/embe
0x10793363c: 64 2f 58 46 67 45 59 75 35 71 66 36 38 3f 61 75  d/XFgccu5qf68?a
```

If you want some useful Aliases and Scripts for `lldb` you can visit https://github.com/DerekSelander/LLDB.  For example, I prefer Derek's script `sections` instead of `image dump sections MyAppBinary`.

Comment: what is `(lldb) section` ? I can't find it as a built-in command ? Is it an aliases you added ? If so what is it alias for ? Thanks

Comment: Great comment @AymenTM. So sorry. I was using the Aliase from these scripts: https://github.com/DerekSelander/LLDB.  Let me update my answer.

Comment: I'll also add that you can use `memory region <some address>` to find the memory region that contains `<some address>`, which can be useful for finding values on the runtime stack.